# Problem with Logic Pro X when using live loops with drum kits

Tags: logic-pro

So, I have encountered a weird problem. I have tried to do the same thing on different versions of Logic, and different versions of MacOS.

What I do is this:
Create a Live Loop track with a software instrument, and add any drum kit to it

fill the cells of that track with content

Set "Quantize start" to Cell End

Activate "Enable performance recording"

Record a performance to the timeline, switching between the cells of the track

When I do the actual performance, everything sounds good. But, when I look at the timeline, the second MIDI region starts about a little too early. It doesn't matter in which order I play the cells. All subsequent regions have the exact length as they should.

Any other software instrument works as expected, it's just when using drum kits that this problem arises.

[image]

As can be seen in the image below, the second Liverpool-region starts to early (all the cells are 2 bars long). After that first switch, all regions are the right length (including when the first cell is called for again).

I have tried this in different projects, different drum kits, drummers, updated Logic Pro, updated MacOS. And the problem still remains.

Any ideas of what causes this, and what can be done about it?

Comment: the first region doesn't end at a bar line. Everything else stems from there. idk logic, but that's what you need to fix first.

Comment: That's the thing... the clip I'm using is exactly two bars long. If I copy-paste it, it has the right length, or when I use it as anything else than the first region when recording.